# How to filter data to plot based on two selectInputs in Shiny

Tags: r, input, shiny, subset

I have a shiny application, where I want to plot data based on periodic selection. Primarily I was selecting data based on one input id, that was year. And the application was working [perfectly](https://drive.google.com/open?id=12Cwm9907HyuRfWoPUOvWgzTrSFvEy_BK).
 Now I have created functionality of `from` & `to`, & I would like to cut data based on these [selection](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1aR_8kvFT6kQ9gjPfah7T5LPSanb8twwv).

Now I am having two input ids. My intention is that in `from` I select 2014 & in `to` if I select 2017, the plot should select the data `2014:2017`, & it should dynamically change in accordance with selection for both the entries. But, `subset` function is not working with two inputIDs.

Primarily, my `wellPanel` was:

```
selectInput(inputId = "n_rows",label = "Select period to plot",choices = c(),selected = c(),multiple = T)
```

& in server, the line subsetting the data based on selection, was:

```
plotdata <- subset(rawdata, date %in% input$n_rows)
```

It was working perfectly.

Now, I have written the `from` , `to` functionality

```
selectInput(inputId = "from_rows",label = "Start period to plot",choices = c(),selected = c(),multiple = F),
```

and

```
selectInput(inputId = "to_rows",label = "End period to plot",choices = c(),selected = c(),multiple = F)
```

In server, I have written:

```
plotdata <- subset(rawdata, date %in% c(input$from_rows:input$to_rows))
```

This is not working. Please refer to the attached image so view the screen of my [image: present app]. 
 I will click the `Plot_Pred` button to plot, which currently is not working.

The plot should come by considering data from start selection to the end selection. Please guide me on how I can make the `subset` function work.

Please find attached the [image: old app screenshot] too.
TIA!

Comment: Please provide us with a full [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Comment: I solved my problem, using ```which``` for corresponding selection of column values